# using redux store's instance of dispatch vs. passing in dispatch as parameter

Tags: javascript, redux, middleware, react-redux

In the [docs](http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/Middleware.html), Dan doesn't give much reasoning for changing the way dispatch is passed into middleware. He just says this:

> But there's also a different way to enable chaining. The middleware
>   could accept the next() dispatch function as a parameter instead of
>   reading it from the store instance.

What is the reason for this? To me, it just looks more weird now that the code inside `applyMiddleware` will take 2 arguments with store and dispatch, rather than just store alone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking weird is not a problem.

```
const logger = store => next => action => {
  console.log('dispatching', action)
  let result = next(action)
  console.log('next state', store.getState())
  return result
}
```

Note that functional languages have this format by default and there it's completely normal.

The reason this is done is because monkey patching has not established itself as a recommended programming method. Passing the `next` to the function is more flexible and doesn't require anything of the function being called (a developer's function) thereby placing less burden on the developer and lowering the chances of errors.

Finally, Dan likes to explain why he's coding things a certain way, but as lib users, we lowly developers are not the decision makers. The [decision has already been made](http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/Middleware.html#the-final-approach) and this is the way to use middleware in Redux. You can always fork Redux and modify it to your liking but note that the power of Redux is not the code inside the lib, but the code attached to it by 3rd party developers. By not playing along, you'd forgo all that power.

Comment: The "format" (more accurately defined as a technique) is called [currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying).

Answer (score 1):

This is a very frequently asked question, and one that I'm going to add to the Redux FAQ shortly.

The short answer is that Redux is heavily influenced by Functional Programming principles, and currying was the approach that Dan and Andrew happened to settle on while doing initial design.  Once that was chosen, it's basically stayed that way for compatibility.

The original design was discussed in Redux [issue #55](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/pull/55), and Dan proposed a rewrite and then rejected his own proposal in [issue #1744](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/issues/1744).